# WebStorm hints to sub-dependencies

Tags: npm, webstorm

The main goal in our project is to have only one dependency to our Core package. Core package should include all other dependencies, like React, axios, Material UI, etc.

Problem is, WebStorm autocomplete and hints don't work, when npm packages are not in package.json, but only as dependency of Core package.

Any advise to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`node-modules` folder is auto-excluded from indexing for better performance, only direct dependencies listed in `package.json` are indexed.
You can manually un-exclude the required modules by tight-clicking the `node_modules/<package_name>` folder and selecting **Mark directory as/Not excluded**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for advise. However, we are going to have many projects and manually including all dependency folders we use, seems like a pain. Isn't there some way, how to automatically add dependencies to "parent" package.json when installing package?

Comment: not sure I follow you... `npm i <package>` adds the package to `"dependencies": {}` list of a `package.json`. But your goal is to have only a single dependency listed there, as far as I can see from your issue description. So, as adding packages as explicit dependencies is not an option, you have to un-exclude them manually as I suggested